# Structure nav to show only specified entry ids?

Tags: structure

Is it possible to have a structure:nav tag that only brings in the entry ids that are specified? I've tried the other way round and excluding all other ids but it seems a bit overkill and doesn't actually work.

Any help would be awesome.

Thank you.

Comment: Yup, you can use the structure entries plugin.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries

Comment: Wil this still allow me to display entries in structure order?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can remember.

Comment: Just experimenting with it now and all appears to be working correctly. Thank you :)

Comment: I'll add it as answer below. If you could mark it as correct that would be super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you sure can by using the structure entries plugin.

devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries